# Sort vector into repeating sequence when sequential values are missing R

Tags: r, sorting, seq

I would like to take a vector such as this:

`x <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)`

and sort this vector into a repeating sequence maintaining the hierarchical order of 1, 2, 3 when values are absent.

return: `c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,2)`

Comment: How do you define missing/absent?

Comment: @NelsonGon so in the example above the sequence begins to breakdown in the vector. There are not enough 1's and 3's to complete the sequence 1,2,3 additional times. So instead I'd like to complete that sequence as best as possible at the end of the vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create the `order` based on the sequence of 'x'

```
x[order(ave(x, x, FUN = seq_along))]
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 2
```

---

Or with `rowid` from`data.table`

```
library(data.table)
x[order(rowid(x))]
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 2
```